# Establishing UDP communication with python

Tags: python, networking, udp, communication, packet

So, I have this code here.  This sender script give's me the output properly.

```html
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 0
MESSAGE = "Hi, can you listen to this?"

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "message:", MESSAGE

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

I tried to use this script on another host and try to establish a communication between the two. (Both the systems are on the same network ex. 00.000.00.xxx , only the xxx part varies)

```html
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 0

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data
```

Here is the output

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bshivaku/Desktop/SEnd_Udp_packets.py", line 9, in <module>
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

I used the ip address of the **receiver** on the **sender script** and **sender** ip address on **receiver** 
I am sure I made a mistake with the **UDP_PORT** so i used **PORT**= 0 and tried. How to request for port number?  How do I establish the connection? If not the port, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending a message use a specific port, for example `UDP_PORT=8765`, otherwise if `UDP_PORT` is set to 0 then the system will chose a random port for you.

Use the ip address of the receiver host in the sender script and bind to any interface on the receiver script.

On the receiving side use the same UDP port number configured in the sender script.

receiver:

```
import socket
UDP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
UDP_PORT = 8543

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data
```

sender:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "<ip_address_of_receiver>"
UDP_PORT = 8543
MESSAGE = "Hi, can you listen to this?"

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "message:", MESSAGE

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Aside the UDP addresses setting there are not any problems on python side.

About the error:

```
[Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

This normally stems from an attempt to bind to an address that is not valid for the local computer: so it seems that the loopback address 127.0.0.1 it is not configured on your machine.

Investigate on the sys admin side, for example check if the IPv4 network stack is enabled on your machine.

Comment: Ahh.. worked like a charm..I also tried with using a particular port number on both sides with adding the actual ip address instead of 0.0.0.0. had not worked. So what is this 0.0.0.0 for? something like open port that listens from all addresses?

Comment: For convention 0.0.0.0 means all ip addresses on local machine, so your socket listen for incoming messages on all network interfaces.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. :)

Comment: Welcome on SO! Don't forget to accept the answer it it worked for you.

Comment: So, now I have another question. I read that for sending  data as payload of udp i need to consider the headers of ethernet, ipv4 or v6 and the then come udp. So in the above example, is that ethernet and ipv considered? because the source and port are assigned but I quite don't understand if the headers of ethernet or internet and ipv4 or v6 has been considered, because the udp header also has a 2 byte source and destination port). Can any one share any example of such program for understanding better? or kindly explain..